# Is there a VBA function to send a QUIT message to the SMTP server, as in the .NET Dispose()

Tags: vba, ms-access, smtp, ms-access-2016

My SMTP service provider only allows 5 simultaneous SMTP connections, how do I instruct my MS Access VBA CDO send mail to dispose or quit the connection after an email.

I was expecting that

```
    Set config = Nothing
    Set mail = Nothing
```

would quit the connection and free up the resources.

Answer (score 0):

Before and after sending a message, try to reset the Connection:

```
CDO.Message.Connection = Nothing
CDO.Message.Connection = YourConnection
' ...
CDO.Message.Connection = Nothing
```

Comment: The CDO.Message Library Constants don't have anything similar to Connection or Quit.